# How does BufferedReader.readline().split(" ") work in Java if nested methods are not allowed?

Tags: java, input

I saw a code,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
String []parts = br.readLine().split(" ");
```

Can anyone help me understand how are we able to split the result of br.readline() in the same line.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested methods are not allowed"?

Comment: As in python we can declare a function inside a function. But as far as I have studied, we cannot declare a method inside a method in Java. @tgdavies

Comment: That's called [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). `br.readLine()` returns a String object, so you can call any method of `String` on its return result. It has nothing to do with "nested methods" (whatever you think those are)

Comment: No functions are declared in the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks @OHGODSPIDERS , found exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There's no nested method.

Call `br.readLine()` [1] returns instance of `String` (object) on which you directly call its method `split()` [2] without "saving" it to temporary variable.

The code can be rewritten as:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line  = br.readLine();
String [] parts = line.split(" ");
```

The code might be rewritten even like this:

```
String [] parts = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().split(" ");
```

--

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)